# Get MAGE_MODE within a template file or a block

Tags: magento2, php, blocks, template, developer-mode

How can I get the current `MAGE_MODE` value, defined in the `env.php` file, from a template (.phtml) file or a block class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `getMode()` method in `\Magento\Framework\App\State` class. In your block:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State $_appState **/
protected $_appState;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
)
{
    $this->_appState = $appState;
}

public function getMode() {
    return $this->_appState->getMode();
}
```